# Async response processing with HTTP4S

Tags: java, scala, http

I started looking at HTTP4S library for "async" HTTP service with Scala. Here, async means "non-blocking" (Ex: Servlet 3.1 async servlet) response processing, where the request thread is freed until response is available.

I'm not sure how to achieve this with HTTP4S. When I run the streaming sample(using streamz Process/Task response handler), I can see one of the threads from blaze server pool is waiting for response(This is different from my worker thread which generates the response).

Is it possible to have truly async server with HTTP4S?

Answer (score -1):

Actually I found that it is async. For testing, I added a breakpoint which suspended the JVM. JVM was suspended before callback registration can happen on main thread. Once I added a sleep on the response processing thread(and then set a breakpoint), I can see all request pool threads are in wait state.